# How would I unit test jdbcTemplate.query that have overrides?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a class that uses multiple get methods the returns

```
 public int getCurrNum(String Name) {

    // query clearances table to return an int that represents the clearance level
    String sql = "SELECT number FROM clearances WHERE '" + Name + "' = name;";
    //String.format("SELECT number FROM clearances WHERE '%s' = name;",clearanceName);
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
}
```

which I understand I can use Mockito with a statement like  `Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(1);`

But that is not really testing values that are being passed in because I am just telling it to return a value I want. I want to make sure all these methods return what the parameters are specially passing in. We have a user token with user details being sent in. We also have more JdbcTemplates such as

```
 public List<String> getCurr(String currCountry) {

    // query alliances table to return a list of alliance tags that countain the
    // user's country tag
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE '" + currCountry + "' = ANY(access_tags) ;";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<String>() {
        @Override
        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getString(1);
        }
    });
```

Then the last methods combines everything and has this return statement that uses all these setters from another class.

```
    // return list of appropriately filtered missions
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Mission>() {
        @Override
        public OtherClass mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {
            OtherClass m = new OtherClass();
            m.setNumber(rs.getInt(1));
            m.setName(rs.getString(2));
            m.setLastCheckinDate(rs.getString(3));
            m.setLocation(rs.getString(4));
            m.setCurrLocation(rs.getString(5));
            m.setFinalLocation(rs.getString(6));
            m.setTags(rs.getString(7));
            return m;
        }
    });
}
```

But I am not sure how to test these statements. Without using the Mockito.when commands, they always turn out null. We have this information in a database .xml file for the column and rows so it knows what information to grab to fill in the lists. Do I need to mock a mock db or something to test this?

Comment: So for every test you first need to understand what is it you're testing?  If it's just the method, that given some Name value, it constructs the SQL correctly, then that's easily done with mockito.  If you're trying to test "how does this code work when run against a database in some known state" then you need a more complex test harness (anything run against a db isn't really a unit test, either.  Not wrong, just not a unit test).  There are ways to test against test dbs, H2 is a common tool for this, as it can be included as a java dependency and doesn't need a separate install.

Comment: H2 Link, btw: https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: If I was just doing the unit test with Mockito about constructing the SQL correctly, is there a way to do it without doing something like `Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn` Because wouldn't I want to test it getting the specific values instead of anyString?

Comment: `Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(ArgumentMatchers.eq("Some string literal"), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn` would work.  If you want to dig more into row matcher you might have to make it an addressable public class.  Also, for more advanced matching, mockito has the concept of argument captors: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor